# Plotting global contour data that crosses both the meridian and the dateline

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

So I have two different datasets.  I have one that is a polar orbiting satellite that starts near the north pole goes down towards Africa then goes over the south pole and back up the Atlantic ocean.  I also have a Global composite of a number of Geostationary satellites.  That grid is a full global coverage from -90 to 90 latitude, and 0 to -0.2 (around the dateline) longitudes.

So when I plot my polar orbiting data.  I get a funny striping across the northern hemisphere where the satellite crosses the dateline.  Like this...

[polar orbiting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDHjO.png)

I did a search and found that if I do this to my longitude values

```
lons[lons < 0] += 360
```

that it then removes the strange striping.  I think it actually just moves the stripes to the southern hemisphere (where is crosses the meridian), but since that area is all "missing" values it doesn't show on the plot, so I don't care.

[polar orbiting data - longitudes all positive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLNC0.png)

So now there is the problem of the full Global dataset.  When I plot it without converting all the longitudes to positive values, it has quite a few stripes going on.  I believe it is every place there is rain that crosses the dateline.

[Global dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCOvv.png)

When I try to apply the "fix" that worked for the polar data I get a really nasty very uninformative error.

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

There is no traceback or anything, so I'm not even sure if it is matplotlib or cartopy or what that is throwing the error.

I've tried cropping the image by using set_extent() but it still has the stripes.

Any ideas how to fix this, or how to trick matplotlib/cartopy into plotting the data correctly?

---

Adding code, but not sure how much it will actually be of help.  It is pretty basic.  The issue is more with the fact that the rain data covers the full globe.

```
normal_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0)
pos_lons = lon_data.copy()
pos_lons[pos_lons < 0] += 360
cs = plt.contourf(pos_lons, lat_data, rr_data, clevs, cmap=cmap,
                      transform=normal_proj, norm=norm)
```

Comment: would help to add  the matplotlib/cartopy code that you're using to generate the images.

Comment: Not really sure which parts of the code would be helpful.  It is pretty standard stuff other than the dataset itself covering the full globe, but I can't easily include that part in a copy-paste of the code.

Comment: Added something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into an annoying, but difficult to track down [bug in CartoPy](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/791). Basically, in transforming the contours and clipping them to the map extent it generates some Shapely geometries incorrectly. Some things that have worked to get around the problem (not solve it) include slightly adjusting the map boundaries and adjusting the contour levels.

Comment: Thanks.  At this point doing the mapping isn't critical to my final product, it was more of just a sanity check that I was reading in data correctly, so I'm just going to leave it as is, unless cartopy gets fixed in the future.